# How to click a specific div with a specific class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm new at coding in puppeteer, and I wanted to know how to make it click this: ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZclR.png))

The code I have rn is this one:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
     const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
     const page = await browser.newPage();
     await page.goto('page link is here');
     await page.screenshot({ path: 'game.png' });

     const [button] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'Accept')]");
     if (button) {
        await button.click();
     }
            I want to click it here.
     await page.screenshot({ path: 'test.png' });
     await browser.close();
})();
```

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element highlighted in the screenshot is the one to be clicked, you can simply:

```
await page.click('.shipyard-item');
```

I'd like to suggest the excellent [puppeteer documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options) to consult with for most the use cases.